# oracle: Именованные параметры или их порядок?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

даже не знаю с чего начать... 
.net-овская программа работает с oracle.
для передачи данных используются именованные параметры.
работа ведется несколько лет.
когда-то все работало четко, но сейчас обнаружилось, что имена параметров не имеют значения, а их порядок имеет. 
подскажите, куда копать

обращение происходит к хранимым процедурам, параметры передаются стандартно:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = GetConnection().CreateCommand())
{
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "Owner.Package.Procedure";
            OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter();
            p1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
            p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p1.ParameterName = "param1";        
            OracleParameter p2 = new OracleParameter();
            p2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
            p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            p2.ParameterName = "param2";        
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

как должно выполняться: при изменении порядка параметров всё должно работать корректно.

как сейчас: если поменять параметры местами (а их тип одинаковый) то процедура выполнится, но с некорректными данными.

Comment: Покажите главное sql-запрос. Ну и код на с/с# который выполняет запрос. Если в sql-запросе `?` то важен порядок.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да c#, поправил теги

Comment: @nick_n_a выполняется хранимая процедура, парметры передаются стандартным способом

Comment: У вас не видно sql-код. Две точки мне ничего не говорят.

Comment: @nick_n_a там нет запроса там имя хранимой процедуры

Comment: Странно, теперь видно. Вроде должно работать.

Comment: @nick_n_a да, все работает, но применяется порядок параметров. например, если убрать p1.ParameterName = "param1"; - ничего не изменится. а должен принимать параметры именно по имени, а не по порядку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всё просто, для этого есть специальное свойство

cmd.BindByName = true;